# Assert statement for junit

Tags: java, junit

My method returns null sometimes and not null  values so how to write a assert for those scenarios

example:`assertNotNull(some statement)`

Comment: put some more code

Comment: So may ask yourself : what do I want to assert ? Because if even you, don't know what will be the result, I don't know what you can check is the result is "random"

Comment: Set up multiple tests that exercise all code paths through the function. It's not clear what kind of information you're looking for, but it sounds like you'd be better off doing some basic testing tutorials before going much further.

Comment: How on earth is this getting any upvotes. From a technical standpoint it's nowhere near complete, from the effort/research/crafting side it's well below average. It can't be answered as written and meets none of the SO criteria for asking questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple:

```
@Test
public void testFooGivesNotNull() {
  assertNotNull(foo.bar(somethingLeadingToNotNull));
}

@Test
public void testFooGivesNull() {
  assertNull(foo.bar(somethingElseLeadingToNull));
}
```

In other words: you do that by identifying the possible test cases, to then write at least one test for each of the possible paths.

And for the record: returning *null* is rarely a good idea. That *null* is the first step towards running into a NullPointerException. Consider alternatives, such as

- returning a special object that represents "null"
- returning an `Optional`
- throwing an exception

Comment: Ohh, did you mean [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)? That's a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Just call your function and add an error message:

```
Assert.assertNotNull(someFunction(), "This should not be null");
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to use Assert.assertNotNull is via static import.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;


assertNotNull(yourValueTobeCheckAsNull, "This should not be null");
```